# Manually setting time zone in Django form

Tags: python, django, datetime

I've read though a lot of documentation and other SO questions regarding the correct and incorrect methods of changing the timezone on a datetime object. I am aware that the proper usage is pytz and using .localize and/or .astimezone and not using .replace.

I am trying to figure out how to allow the user to input the time zone in the form. I don't want to use localized browser settings to determine the user's time zone; the user should be able to specify what timezone is applied to the datetime object before it is saved to the database. I have already put a TimeZoneField from [django-timezone-field](https://github.com/mfogel/django-timezone-field) on the model, but I can't figure out how to properly apply it to the datetime object.

Everything I have tried actually converts the time. Is this something that I will have to do in javascript in the template instead of in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the datetime naive by using `.replace(tzinfo=None)`. ([ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace))

Then apply the timezone from the timezone field using `tz.localize`. ([ref](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic))

Comment: Using this method by overriding the form_valid function in the view seems to work, but it also feels very hack-y. I feel as though there should be a way to get the form to pass naive datetime object.

Thanks for the answer though. It'll at least get me by for now if I can't find a cleaner way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You might override the save() method on the model as follows:

```
import pytz
from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    """A model with a datetime field whose timezone appears in a separate field."""

    starts_at = models.DateTimeField("Start date and time")
    timezone = models.CharField("Timezone", max_length=128, 
                   choices=[(tz, tz) for tz in pytz.all_timezones if tz.startswith("US")])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tz = pytz.timezone(self.timezone)
        self.starts_at = self.starts_at.replace(tzinfo=None)
        self.starts_at = tz.localize(self.starts_at)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```